# Why Android IAP initializing but not working?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I am using this library to implement in app purchase in my app.

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

I added this code to my gradle.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
}
```

I added the permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

I declared variable

```
 BillingProcessor bp;
```

I used(to test it) bp in onCreate method after setContentView

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "x", null,new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
                Log.d("purchase2","purchased");
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
                Log.d("purchase2","error");
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingInitialized() {
                Log.d("purchase2","initialized");
            }
            @Override
            public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                Log.d("purchase2","historyrestored");
            }
        });


        bp.purchase(this, "y");
```

The code does not run onProductPurchased method. It only runs onBillingInitialized method. I looked verbose logcat. There is no line about **purchased** when I can see **initialized** line.

As a result, how can I solve my problem? Why does not it work?

X and Y values are correct, I checked them in Google Play Console.

Comment: Have you launched the billing flow? Billing flow launches the screen to purchase your SKUs after the purchase onPurchasePurchased will be invoked.

Comment: How can I launch billing flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should call

```
bp.initialize();
```

in oncreate like this

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    
       bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "x", null,new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
                    Log.d("purchase2","purchased");
                }
                @Override
                public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
                    Log.d("purchase2","error");
                }
                @Override
                public void onBillingInitialized() {
                    Log.d("purchase2","initialized");
                }
                @Override
                public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                    Log.d("purchase2","historyrestored");
                }
            });

bp.initialize();
```

and call

`bp.purchase(this, "y");`

in button click event.

you should also override Activity's onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }  
}
```

good luck!

Comment: I tried initialize() method before purchase, there was the same scenario. Only initialized method is called. 

Why button click is needed? I just want to test so I used it in onCreate. Does not it work without button click event?

Comment: Only modification is to add bp.purchase to onclick method. Then it works without any problem!